# How to reshape Tensor in C++ like Caffe's Blob

Tags: c++, tensorflow, caffe

I want to use tensors of dynamic shapes in C++. For example, I want add a new op in tensorflow, but I do not know the output's shape in the beginning. If I use Caffe, I can firstly reshape the output blob to the maximum size I will use, and reshape to it is actual size in the end.
How can do it with tensorflow's Tensor?.

Comment: This `mshadow` library https://github.com/dmlc/mshadow/tree/master could help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about the shape of your Variable yet, leave one or more dimension of that `tf.Variable` as `None`. For example:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1,1])
```

Tensorflow also has a [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape) function that you can use in the same fashion as caffe. For example:

```
x2 = tf.reshape(x, [-1, dim])           # -1 means "all"
```

Comment: but I should use C++, how to do it with C++?